# Objects are not valid as a React child (). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: reactjs

I want to paste the saved values of my state after the api call and it appears to not be showing.I can see the values on the console working perfectly . 
Any ideas how I can show the this.state.card1 values after the api call?

import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios';

```
class Details extends Component {

state={
card1:[]
}

 componentDidMount() {
 axios.get(`....`)
.then(res =>
    {console.log(res.data);
    this.setState({card1:res.data.data});
    console.log(this.state.card1)
  })
 .catch(err=>console.log(err));

 }
  render() {
  return (
  <div>
   { this.state.card1}
  </div>
 )
}
}

export default  Details;
```

Comment: what is the shape of the objects inside the array `this.state.card1` ?

Comment: {name: "", text: "", card_type: "spell", type: null, family: null, …}

Comment: depends what you want to do ? The message is pretty explicit, you cannot render simple `object`, it should be either `React Element` or primitives values. What is the expected output in your example ?

Comment: I want to output the values of the res.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the render() return:

```
   <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.card1)}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return an array of elements, you can do this with `.map`:

```
{ this.state.card1.map(o => <div>{o.text}</div>)}
```

Note that its [highly advised to add the `key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for each element.